# Django admin model within model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to make poll app. There will be polls with some questions and every question have some choices. Is there any way how to add questions within poll and then choices within questions(something like nested inlines) in admin form?

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    poll_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Question(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)   
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the admin site is great for the developer in checking in on current site data and tweaking what's already there. But when you're trying to make app functionality, such as creating entire polls, that's where you want to start writing your own code. Your finished product should not make use of the admin site, in the same way an end user should never directly interact with a database.

At this point, I would create a section of your site that requires admin (or staff or whatever permission groups you wish to create) rights to access, and set up your own forms to create polls, questions, and answers, and link them properly to create the correct Poll, Question, and Choice objects in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with the help of a custom app. Take a look at the [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) package. I've been using it for a while, so far so good.

```
class ChoiceInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Choice

class QuestionInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Question
    inlines = [ChoiceInline, ]

class PollAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = Poll
    inlines = [QuestionInline, ]
```